# Why isn't .replace() working on a large generated string from escodege.generate()?

Tags: javascript, replace, code-generation, escodegen

I am attempting to generate some code using escodegen's [.generate() function](https://github.com/estools/escodegen/wiki/API) which gives me a string.

Unfortunately it does not remove completely the semi-colons (only on blocks of code), which is what I need it to do get rid of them myself. So I am using the the `.replace()` function , however the semi-colons are not removed for some reason.

Here is what I currently have:

```
  generatedCode = escodegen.generate(esprima.parseModule(code), escodegenOptions)
  const cleanGeneratedCode = generatedFile.replace(';', '')
  console.log('cleanGeneratedCode ', cleanGeneratedCode) // string stays the exact same.
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something perhaps?

Comment: Chances are it is removing a single semicolon.  Instead of using a substring, try `generatedFile.replace(/;/g, '')`.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed (should have known better...). Put that as an answer so that I can mark it as the resolution for the problem :)

Comment: use RegExp for replace all :  generatedFile.replace(new RegExp(';', 'g'), '');

Comment: @mscdeveloper I had never seen that before. It sure makes it easier for future use when a specific character all over the string. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), if you provide a substring instead of a regex

> It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression. Only the first occurrence will be replaced.

So, the output probably isn't *exactly* the same as the code generated, but rather the first semicolon has been removed.  To remedy this, simply use a regex with the "global" flag (`g`).  An example:

```
const cleanGenereatedCode = escodegen.generate(esprima.parseModule(code), escodegenOptions).replace(/;/g, '');
console.log('Clean generated code: ', cleanGeneratedCode);
```